# How can I wrap trim around a corner where the floors have different levels?

Tags: repair, floor, trim, joints, level

My floors are not exactly level and floor quarter round molding does not tie together. Any ideas on how we can make this look good?

[image: floor molding]

Comment: Something ornamental oriented vertically. I'm thinking analogous to https://www.amazon.com/Poplar-Outside-Radius-Corner-Molding/dp/B083RH8L2B/. Analogous. I'm not advocating for that particular ugly product.

Comment: Some kind of corner block?

Comment: This question should not be closed as being about decoration. It's about carpentry.

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be:

Buy a new transition strip and have it go all the way across.

Cut a return and glue it to the end of the lighter quarter round.

Make a return for the darker quarter round and glue it to finish before butting into your new transition strip.

Here is an [example video](https://youtube.com/watch?v=OrWJG9K_nfo) of the quarter round return.